# How can omp parallel work with omp single?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing

I am reading a [Guide to OpenMP](http://bisqwit.iki.fi/story/howto/openmp/#TaskDirectiveOpenmp%203%200Only) and I am failing to understand the `omp single` directive.

```
struct node { int data; node* next; };
extern void process(node* );
void increment_list_items(node* head)
{
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        #pragma omp single
        {
            for(node* p = head; p; p = p->next)
            {
                #pragma omp task
                process(p); // p is firstprivate by default
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Why is `omp parallel` run before `omp single`? Isn't this pointless? Doesn't parallel create the workers and then single just restricts to a single thread anyways for the function? Is this just taking care of some of the overhead when you know you will be using those workers inside of the single thread anyways?